# Oracle before update trigger - dynamically loop through columns with old and new value

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-update, beforeupdate

I'm writing a database trigger for a history function.

I had the hope that there is a chance to use one trigger for multiple tables. Also I don't want to check every single column by name.

So I tried to create the trigger using dynamical SQL like this:

```
  FOR columnItem IN (SELECT column_name 
                        FROM all_tab_columns 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER(tableName))
   LOOP
   -- how to use columnItem.column_name for the loop
   -- like :new.[columnItem.column_name] or something like that
       if :new.NAME != :old.NAME Then
         INSERT INTO HISTORY 
         VALUES (HIS_SEQUENCE.nextval, tableName, :new.LOCAL_ID, columnItem.column_name, 'OLD', 'NEW', sysdate(), 'STACKOVERFLOW');
      End If;
   END LOOP;
```

That's not possible, is it?
Hope you know a way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `trigger` is fired when an event occurs on the table it's created. `:new` refers to the the new value which is result of the DML operation on the table. So incase you want the same value to be inserted to all the other tables it;s possible but when you say `:new.[columnItem.column_name]` ..this kind of construct is not possible to achieve in Oracle,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The goal isn't to insert the same value  to other tables rather to use the trigger for other tables too.. to use the same code for other tables, thats the reason why i tried it with something like ":new.[columnItem.column_name] ". Do you know another way to do this dynamicle ?

Comment: `Trigger` is created on a single table and yes you can insert the :new values to many tables but cannot run the loop you are trying to do. Its not possible